Problems reading a csv file with panda's, tokenizing error
I am trying to make a graph of a csv file, I attached a link of the file, I am trying to use panda's to make a graph where the "Current I_A1/A" column is on the x axis and the "Voltage U_B2/V" is on the y axis.
I wrote the following code,
first cell:
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')`

Second cell
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sympy import S, symbols, printing
import scipy.optimize as sci
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
#Importing all the relevant packages for the code, plotting, finding the best fit, analyzing our data and error analysis
file=pd.read_csv(r'/content/drive/MyDrive/Dataset 1(no offset part1 plate 1).csv')
x_axis=file['Current I_A1/A ']
y_axis=file['Voltage U_B2/V']`

I get an error: "Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 3, saw 6"
Here is the link to the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fbu7ulgNEr3IvLdwX9q5o-2oT0jKGYmH/view?usp=sharing
I dont know how to fix it, I triend specifying engine type but that gives other errors
I triend specifying engine type but it didnt work

pandas will guess the separator - in your case it guessed wrong. This is a semi-colon separated file, so use pd.read_csv(..., sep=";")

I changed it, now I get en error "KeyError: 'Current I_A1/A ' "

That's an error on the next line. The column label is "Current I_A1 / A" without the trailing whitespace.

Thanks, now how can I get the x_axis into an array, now I get an error "'value' must be an instance of str or bytes, not a float"

Your Q was about pd.read_csv and @tdelaney gave you the answer. The next course of action will be for you to try to create your 'graph', and come back with a new Q only if you get stuck after showing proper research effort. Here on SO and elsewhere online, you can find a ton of examples / tutorials. If you've exhausted those, and still face issues, by all means, ask another Q and SO users will be very happy to lend a helping hand. Good luck!

A few issues:

Your file uses ; as separator, but pandas is trying to use ,. You need to specify it with the argument sep=';';
The numbers need to be converted to numeric type, since they are imported as strings, which you won't be able to plot in a graph. The file uses commas as decimal separator, which pandas does not support, so you need to replace commas with dots before converting them to numbers with astype.
The column names you're trying to use are different from the ones in the dataframe. You can check that with file.columns.

file = pd.read_csv(r'/content/drive/MyDrive/Dataset 1(no offset part1 plate 1).csv', sep=";")

file = file.replace(r",", ".", regex=True).astype(float)

x = file["Current I_A1 / A"]
y = file["Voltage U_B2 / V"]

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()

This will result in this dataframe:
    Time t / s  Current I_A1 / A  Voltage U_B2 / V  Magn. flux density B_A1 / mT  Voltage U_B1 / V
0        0.000          0.002205           0.00105                       -10.125             0.130
1        0.100          0.002205           0.00110                       -10.170             0.130
2        0.199          0.002205           0.00110                       -10.155             0.130
3        0.301          0.002190           0.00105                       -10.140             0.130
4        0.400          0.002205           0.00110                       -10.185             0.130
5        0.501          0.002160           0.00110                       -10.125             0.130
6        0.600          0.002205           0.00110                       -10.140             0.130
7        0.700          0.002220           0.00110                       -10.155             0.135
8        0.800          0.002220           0.00115                       -10.140             0.130
9        0.900          0.002940           0.00165                       -10.155             0.175
10       1.001          0.003540           0.00205                       -10.125             0.220
11       1.100          0.004275           0.00255                       -10.155             0.255
12       1.200          0.004590           0.00275                       -10.140             0.280
13       1.300          0.004875           0.00300                       -10.140             0.295
14       1.400          0.005430           0.00330                       -10.110             0.325
15       1.500          0.006120           0.00380                       -10.140             0.370
16       1.600          0.006450           0.00405                       -10.110             0.390
17       1.700          0.007080           0.00445                       -10.170             0.430
18       1.801          0.007470           0.00475                       -10.125             0.460
19       1.900          0.008415           0.00535                       -10.140             0.510
20       2.000          0.008925           0.00575                       -10.095             0.545
21       2.100          0.009690           0.00625                       -10.125             0.590
22       2.200          0.010500           0.00680                       -10.140             0.640
23       2.300          0.011805           0.00770                       -10.125             0.720
24       2.400          0.012435           0.00810                       -10.110             0.755
25       2.501          0.013260           0.00870                       -10.140             0.805
26       2.600          0.014280           0.00940                       -10.125             0.870
27       2.700          0.015105           0.00990                       -10.095             0.920
28       2.799          0.015750           0.01040                       -10.110             0.955
29       2.900          0.016590           0.01095                       -10.110             1.010
30       3.001          0.017175           0.01130                       -10.125             1.045
31       3.100          0.017805           0.01175                       -10.140             1.085
32       3.201          0.018405           0.01215                       -10.125             1.120
33       3.300          0.018945           0.01255                       -10.125             1.150
34       3.400          0.019755           0.01310                       -10.140             1.200
35       3.500          0.020340           0.01350                       -10.095             1.235
36       3.600          0.020700           0.01375                       -10.125             1.260
37       3.700          0.021315           0.01420                       -10.110             1.295
38       3.800          0.021795           0.01455                       -10.125             1.330
39       3.900          0.022440           0.01500                       -10.095             1.365
40       4.000          0.023295           0.01555                       -10.110             1.415
41       4.100          0.023835           0.01590                       -10.080             1.445
42       4.199          0.024090           0.01615                       -10.110             1.465
43       4.300          0.024975           0.01675                       -10.110             1.520
44       4.400          0.025575           0.01715                       -10.110             1.555
45       4.500          0.026265           0.01765                       -10.110             1.600
46       4.600          0.027300           0.01830                       -10.110             1.660
47       4.701          0.028185           0.01890                       -10.095             1.715
48       4.801          0.029100           0.01950                       -10.080             1.770
49       4.900          0.029640           0.01990                       -10.125             1.800
50       5.002               NaN           0.02030                       -10.035             1.840
51       5.100          0.030800           0.02070                       -10.065             1.875
52       5.200          0.031150           0.02105                       -10.095             1.900
53       5.299          0.032000           0.02160                       -10.125             1.950
54       5.400          0.032500           0.02195                       -10.095             1.980
55       5.500          0.033050           0.02230                       -10.110             2.010
56       5.600          0.033100           0.02225                       -10.035             2.010
57       5.700          0.033050           0.02230                       -10.095             2.010
58       5.800          0.033050           0.02230                       -10.110             2.010
59       5.900          0.033050           0.02230                       -10.080             2.010

And this plot:


Thanks that worked alot, I used the following lines to make a best fit through the scatter plot, only te line of the best fit is shifted all the way above for some reason:
"fit1, covariance1 = sci.curve_fit(f, x_axis, y_axis)
plt.plot(x_axis, f(x_axis,*fit1), label='Best Fit')

i think there is a problem with your file column name.
try changing name of the column.
I tried something shown below and it worked.
file_path='/content/sample_data/Dataset_1.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, index_col='A;B') #'A;B' is the name of the column inn .csv filr
print(df)

So A and B are the names of the columns that I want to graph?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
